# Is C a single threaded language

Tags: c, multithreading

I was recently reading "The C Programming language" by Ritchie, I noticed that C is a single threaded language. Well I want to know what actually is the difference between Single threaded language and multi threaded language. If C is a single threaded, then is it asynchronous or synchronous?

Comment: What do you mean by "single threaded language"? That you can not start threads? Or something else? Because Java is just as "single threaded" as C then.

Comment: Node.js is a single threaded language which in background uses multiple threads to execute asynchronous code, so do you mean C is just like Node.js? So can C work asynchronously?

Comment: You mention Java, which is a ***very different*** language from JavaScript which is what node.js is based on. It would be better if you juist edit your question to make it more clear what you mean.

Comment: A language doesn't *work asynchronously*. It's the created processes that do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The C programming language is now a standard**, so read the [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) specification, that is [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Remember that **a programming language is a *specification*** (so is defined in some technical report) not a software. Ritchie's book is about an older version of C (written at a time -the 1980s- where multicore computers and multithreading did not exist or where very unusual, and Ritchie himself did not have any such computer or system). The C standard defines (loosely) the behavior of C implementations (and [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is a very important and tricky notion in it).

There is some [thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread) support in C11.

You could also use C99 (or even C11) with some external libraries, such as [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) on POSIX, providing threads.

You could view threads (and processes, and files) as some features or abstractions provided by [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system). A language specification usually don't tell much about them (for example, most OSes have [directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)), but the C standard don't tell anything about these).

Actually, if you read the C11 standard carefully, you'll probably notice that a computer hardware is not even required (just implicitly subsumed) by it. In principle a C implementation could be a team of humans (and "running a C program on a classroom, considered as a computer" is a nice way of teaching C). In practice, using human slaves as the C implementation is unethical and inefficient, and you should prefer some computer (but what is a computer is not defined by the C11 standard).

Answer (score 3):

It does not depend on the language that it is single or multi-threaded. You can implement threading using libraries. Like in C you have *pthread* library on POSIX in C99 standards. In python also, you can also create the threads. It is basically related to operating system and usually used where you have some input-output operations.

> In computer science, a thread of execution is the smallest sequence of
>   programmed instructions that can be managed independently by a
>   scheduler, which is typically a part of the operating system.

[Threads in OS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operarting-system-thread/)

Comment: Can C work Asynchronously?

Comment: Yes, for that you have to use semaphores. Again a part of OS.